# strtotime('midnight') resulting in 00:05:00

Tags: php, strtotime

I am currently working on a date/time picker based on a locations open / close times. Iterating through the days of the week each entery starts with a timestamp of midnight per day of the week. the following logic results in a 5min addition

```
print_r(strtotime('midnight'));
```

Result:

```
stdClass Object(
    [Sunday] => stdClass Object
        (
            [datetime] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [mdnt] => 2014-05-22 00:05:00
```

Rinse repeat for each day of the week.

My TZ is +5 GMT. If anything I expected the hour places to be incremented, not the seconds.

So the question: where is the 5:00 minutes coming from?

Comment: maybe you have bug in converting time to string, how do you set `datetime->mdnt`?

Comment: show us your code. come on, how do you expect us to help you!?

Comment: We don't see all of your code but `i` is minutes `m` is month. Hint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you posted works. `strtotime` works as expected. You are formatting the date wrong. Try this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('midnight'));
```

Instead of what you have. You almost certainly used this:

```
date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('midnight'));
--------------^
```

Which prints the month for the minutes field instead.

Example

```
<?php
$midnight = strtotime('midnight');

var_dump(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $midnight));
```

Returns:

```
string(19) "2014-05-22 00:00:00"
```

Comment: Well I feel dumb now. I knew this. Obvious resolution is obvious.

Comment: I seriously protest helping someone on basis of code he *might* have, while he is just refusing to show that code.

Comment: @nl-x I agree and voted to close on that basis, but there was an overwhelming possibility of this being the problem since it happens frequently (damn date formatting!). I've done this exact thing a few times

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. It would be better to close-as-duplicate instead :)